# Parameter set name issue

Tags: azure, powershell

i have the following error for Parameter-set

this is the error that i got on one of my runs

**Error Message - "parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. one or more parameters issued can’t be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided"**

this is my code

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Back')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [string]$targetName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [string]$PersonalName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Back')]
    [switch]$backing,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [switch]$Delete,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [switch]$BackAndDelete,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [string]$DeleteType
)
```

All of the parameters function work apart from when I use $backing, that causes the error (screenshot above)

im not to sure on how can i solve that issue? Maybe I should add remove the "[Parameter(...)]" specifications for the "targetname"

could you help me find a fix and make that error go away

Comment: When I invoke your script with `-backing -targetName foo`, it works, both in Windows PowerShell v5.1 and PowerShell 7.3.0. You're saying it doesn't work in v3.0?

Answer (score 0):

> **Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters**:

*When I ran the script in my environment, I received the same error.*

[image]

***Problem cause: PowerShell cannot be able to determine which `parameterset` to utilize. So, to avoid that we need to add*** `defaultparameterset`

To the `cmdletbinding`, I added `DefaultParameterSet`. I've taken your script and modified as shown below. I was able to proceed further successfully.

```
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Back')]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Back')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [string]$targetName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [string]$PersonalName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Back')]
    [switch]$backing,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [switch]$Delete,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [switch]$BackAndDelete,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'BackAndDelete')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Delete')]
    [string]$DeleteType
)
```

***Output:***

[image]